# get parent element with scala-scraper

Tags: scala, dom

I have the following code, using [scala-scraper](https://github.com/ruippeixotog/scala-scraper):

```
val browser = JsoupBrowser()
println(text((browser.parseString(html) >> "h2:contains(Some text)")))
```

This seems to work ok, but, I want to get the parent element of the h2. Is there a way to reach the parent element?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out. You have to use the element extractor, like so:

```
element("h2:contains(Some text)").parent
```